# CSV, add column in first position and fill the first Column with filename

Tags: c#, csv

I have a lot of different CSV files with data in it (including headers).
I can't figure it out how to add a column in the first postition and fill the first cells with the filename value (each row).

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can read csv files with simple textreader and append what ever you want at first line.

Comment: You can read here how to get your data from csv file. After you get data from csv file, you need to modify header structure and append row information. Further reading here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1979251.aspx?Add+new+column+in+existing+CSV+file+using+C+. In the related post he adds the column at the end. You must append in front.

Comment: Thanks Raz van Dumitru for the information and the link. In Visual studio 2013  gives the -1 in the follow line"lines[index] += "," + newColumnData[index - 1];" an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case that your csv-Files are small enough to load them in your memory

```
// #1 Read CSV File
string[] CSVDump = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp.csv");

// #2 Split Data
List<List<string>> CSV = CSVDump.Select(x => x.Split(';').ToList()).ToList();

//#3 Update Data
for (int i = 0; i < CSV.Count; i++)
{
    CSV[i].Insert(0, i == 0 ? "Headername" : "Filename");
}

//#4 Write CSV File
File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\temp2.csv", CSV.Select(x => string.Join(";", x)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a column at first position is a special case which can be implemented without CSV parsing. All you need is to prepend every string with the desired value and a comma. The only exception is the very first line which should be prepended with a header name:

```
        string newColumnHeader = "FileName";
        string textToPrepend = @"some\file\name";
        long lineNumber = 0;
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText("output.csv"))
            foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines("input.csv"))
                sw.WriteLine(
                    (lineNumber++ == 0 ? 
                        newColumnHeader :
                        textToPrepend) + 
                    "," + line);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will done little bit more coding. First read the CSV in to `DataTable`

```
public static DataTable ConvertCSVtoDataTable(string strFilePath)
        {
            StreamReader csv = new StreamReader(strFilePath);
            string[] headers = csv .ReadLine().Split(','); 
            DataTable dtCSV = new DataTable();
            foreach (string header in headers)
            {
                dtCSV.Columns.Add(header);
            }
            while (!csv.EndOfStream)
            {
                string[] rows = csv.ReadLine().Split(',');
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
                {
                    dr[i] = rows[i];
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            return dtCSV;
        }
```

Then insert the column in my desire location:

```
 DataColumn Col = dtCSV.Columns.Add("FileName", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
 Col.SetOrdinal(0);
```

After all the value in column return back to CSV:

```
var lines = new List<string>();

string[] columnNames = dataTable.Columns.Cast<datacolumn>().
                                  Select(column => column.ColumnName).
                                  ToArray();

var header = string.Join(",", columnNames);
lines.Add(header);

var valueLines = dt.AsEnumerable()
                   .Select(row => string.Join(",", row.ItemArray));            
lines.AddRange(valueLines );

File.WriteAllLines("File.csv",lines);
```

Comment: what is `dt`? did you mean `dtCSV`?